# Splitting Text By Rows and Columns

Tags: vba, excel, split, delimiter

I am using an Excel macro to retrieve a CSV file from Yahoo Finance. In column A, I have the stock tickers listed as input. I used to run a macro that would insert each ticker into a URL then output the results into column B. Then I would call a function to split the text in column B into columns B through column E.

The function became much faster when I create a concatenated string of URLs and call the URL just once. The main problem is I am receiving the data in the following format:

```
"81.950,342.05B,"Exxon Mobil Corporation Common ",263.71B
81.38,201.29B,"Alibaba Group Holding Limited A",13.56B
754.77,519.78B,"Alphabet Inc.",71.76B
120.57,649.30B,"Apple Inc.",233.72B"
```

**Current Output**
[image: Current Output]

**Expected/Ideal Output**
[image: Expected/Ideal Output]

When I called the URL one ticker at a time, I could separate the necessary data out with the Text to Columns function. Now I need it separated by columns and rows.

```
Sub StockDataPull() 
Dim url As String
Dim http As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Symbol_rng As Range
Dim Output_rng As Range

'Define Last Row in Ticker Range
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Symbol_rng = Range("A5:A" & LastRow).Cells
Set Output_rng = Range("C5:F" & LastRow).Cells

    'Open Yahoo Finance URL
        url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & concatRange(Symbol_rng) & "&f=pj1ns6"
                Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        http.Open "GET", url, False
        http.Send
                    Output_rng = http.responseText
           Set http = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


'The code below is what I used before Sub StockDataPull(). This code calls a URL for each ticker, instead of one URL for all tickers in a concatenated string. It's considerably slower, but it works because it outputs the data two cells away from the ticker, then I call Sub Delimiter() to separate it across the next few consecutive columns.


Sub StockData()
Dim url As String
Dim http As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Symbol_rng As Range

''Define Last Row in Ticker Range
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Symbol_rng = Range("A5:A" & LastRow).Cells

    For Each cell In Symbol_rng

    ''Open Yahoo Finance URL
        url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & cell.Value & "&f=pj1ns6"

        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        http.Open "GET", url, False
        http.Send

        cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2) = http.responseText

        Set http = Nothing

    Next cell

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
        Call Delimiter            
    End Sub

Sub Delimiter()    
''Define Last Row in Ticker Range
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

''Separate the data into four columns
    Range("C5:C" & LastRow).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C5"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

''Unwrap the text
    Range("C5:F" & LastRow).Select
    With Selection
        .WrapText = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where's the part that's not working?

Comment: Have a look at Split function: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php

Comment: Can you also post a sample table of the expected output? But it looks like @GSazheniuk is on the scent, look at `Split`.

Comment: Thanks, I did look at the Split function. I can use that to separate the output data into columns; I just can't figure out how to put it into rows.

Comment: If you have the code to put it in columns, can you post it? It should require just a little tweaking to put in rows instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Let me know if I'm not making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this is not the best way to handle this type of problem, but it should work.

First of all we need to change your `Delimiter` sub (which is good!) so it can work with rows extracted from response:

```
Sub Delimiter(ByVal LastRow)
''Separate the data into four columns
    Range("B1:B" & LastRow).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1:C" & LastRow), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

''Unwrap the text
    Range("B1:F" & LastRow).Select
    With Selection
        .WrapText = False
    End With

End Sub
```

And here is how to split your response in proper way:

```
Sub SplitToLines()
    s = Cells(1, "A")
    If Left(s, 1) = """" Then
        s = Mid(s, 2)
    End If

    If Right(s, 1) = """" Then
        s = Mid(s, 1, Len(s) - 1)
    End If

    resLines = Split(s, vbLf)

    For i = LBound(resLines) To UBound(resLines)
        Cells(i + 1, "B") = resLines(i)
    Next i
    Delimiter (i + 1)

End Sub
```

I just checked on your example and it works. All you need is to put your response in "A1" cell (or change the macro).

Let me know if you are having trouble with it.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a huge help for me. I tinkered with the code to clarify the output range (I realize the code I copied in contradicts the output I specified in my original question) but I'm having one small problem. All of the rows and columns are reformatting except for the last two. Even when I add to the range of tickers, it excludes the last two rows.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your problem? I do not get this part "All of the rows and columns are reformatting except for the last two."

Comment: I wish I could explain it more. This code separates the data by columns and rows, which is exactly what I needed it to do. The problem is it stops at the last two rows. All of the data called from the URL is contained in each cell of the last two rows of the table.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you. Can you edit the split lines and delimiter code such that the output range starts at C5? The ticker inputs are in A5:LastRow, and the data output should go from C5:FLastRow. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you need but you can try to extract the string you need with this function

```
Function ExtractText(ByVal Txt As String) As String
    Txt = Right(Txt, Len(Txt) - InStr(1, Txt, ",""", vbTextCompare) - 1)
    Txt = Left(Txt, InStr(1, Txt, """,", vbTextCompare) - 1)
End Function
```

This extract the company name from the original string you get in the table.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Zealous VB newbie alert.

```
Private Sub so_stub_1()
 'wsSo is the name of my test worksheet
  Dim hdr() As String: hdr = Split("Last Close Price, Market Cap, Company Name, Annual Revenue", ",")
  Dim data() As Variant: data = wsSO.Range("G1:G4")
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim r As Integer
  For i = 1 To UBound(data) 
    r = i + 1 'offset in my test sheet
    wsSO.Range("A" & r & ":D" & r) = Split(data(i, 1), ",")
 Next 'i 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the help - and the disparaging alert.

Comment: @JMoore to be sure that alert was a reference to me!

Comment: Haha oh! Well you could have fooled me. I am definitely the zealous newbie